# Adding interaction terms to show final values in forrest plots? (sjPlot and ggeffects)

Tags: r, ggplot2, mixed-models, sjplot

So I have the two graphs below: one is the coefficients from the property crime values (1st level), and the second, to the right, are the coefficients for violent crime. However, the coefficients to the right are only the differences between property crime and violent crime coefficients, not the actual violent crime coefficients. I'm wondering whether there is a way to added the property crime coefficients to the violent crime coefficients, such that I can get the actual violent crime coefficients.

Here is my model:

```
lmer(log(COUNT + 1) ~ CRIME*( cent.log.pop + cent.log.pop.dens + per_capita_income*black + per_capita_income*white + no.grad.hs  + prop5.17.pov + ma.plus + hs + ba + median_gross_rent+cent.EXP_STUDENT +unemployment_rate + asian +  diff.dem) + officers  + (year|PLACE_ID) + (1|COUNTY_ID) + (1|STATE), control = lmerControl(optimizer= "nloptwrap", calc.derivs = FALSE), na.action = 'na.omit', REML = FALSE, city.v.p = data)
```

[image]

```
plot_model(model, rm.terms = c("cent.log.pop", "CRIMECRIME_VIOLENT:cent.log.pop", "CRIMECRIME_VIOLENT:cent.log.pop.dens", "CRIMECRIME_VIOLENT:per_capita_income", "CRIMECRIME_VIOLENT:black", "CRIMECRIME_VIOLENT:white", "CRIMECRIME_VIOLENT:no.grad.hs", "CRIMECRIME_VIOLENT:prop5.17.pov", "CRIMECRIME_VIOLENT:ma.plus", "CRIMECRIME_VIOLENT:hs", "CRIMECRIME_VIOLENT:ba", "CRIMECRIME_VIOLENT:median_gross_rent", "CRIMECRIME_VIOLENT:cent.EXP_STUDENT", "CRIMECRIME_VIOLENT:unemployment_rate", "CRIMECRIME_VIOLENT:asian", "CRIMECRIME_VIOLENT:diff.dem", "CRIMECRIME_VIOLENT:per_capita_income:black", "CRIMECRIME_VIOLENT:per_capita_income:white", "CRIMECRIME_VIOLENT"), group.terms = c(1,1,2,3,3,1,2,1,3,1,1,3,1,2,3,3,3), axis.labels = labels, title = "9a: Effect Size:  Property Crime", dot.size = .5,line.size = .2)...
```

Comment: How did you create the plot?

Comment: It ends up being a bit of code, but I removed the right hand values from the left, and the left hand values from the right. I'll add to the question, since it's too long to list here.